# $z_n \rightarrow z$ iff $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that $\{ z_n \}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $z_n = x_n + iy_n$.
Let $z=x+iy$. And, let $x_n, y_n, x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $z_n \rightarrow z$ iff $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$.

For "$\Rightarrow $" direction, I've seen it from my textbook saying that "if $\{ z_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, then $\{ x_n \}, \{ y_n \}$ are Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$." (without any reasoning)

Thus, I wanted to start by showing $\{ x_n \}, \{ y_n \}$ are Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, but I am struggling with this one.

To me, it seems right to use the reverse triangle inequality to separate $z_n$ into $|x_n - x_m| $ and $ | y_n - y_m |$, but I'm not sure about how I should proceed from here.

Can I get any hint for this?

Comment: $|a| \leq |a+ib|$ and $|b| \leq |a+ib|$ for $a, b \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675082/42969 or this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2066514/42969. Cauchy sequences are *not* needed here.

Comment: Thanks for all of the hints!

Comment: Here's an informal argument that you can try to make rigorous : 

$z_n$ is small iff $x_n$ and $y_n$ are both small. A sequence is Cauchy if for large $m, n$, $|z_m - z_n|$ is small . Therefore, $(z_n)_{n=1}^\infty $ is Cauchy iff for all sufficiently large $m, n$, $|x_m - x_n|$ and $|y_m - y_n|$ are both small, but this is precisely the condition for $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to be Cauchy.

Comment: @DavidLui: ... but you don't need the Cauchy criterion here because the candidates for the limit are already known.